# Как убрать надпись "переслано от" при пересылке сообщений Aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Нужно переслать сообщение из диалога с ботом одного пользователя в диалог с другим.

То есть пользователь 1 присылает боту видео, а бот присылает это видео пользователю 2.

Я не нашел, как убрать надпись, что сообщение было переслано.

Пользуюсь методом *forward_message*. Возможно в *forward_message* есть какой-то аргумент, позволяющий убрать надпись. Или вообще альтернативный метод.

Кусочек кода:

```
if video_flag == True:

        if message.content_type!='video':
            await bot.send_message(users_id, f"Не похоже на видео. Отправьте ещё раз", reply_markup = inline_topics_8)
        else:
            await bot.send_message(users_id, f"Видео отправлено на модерацию.", reply_markup = inline_topics)
            await bot.forward_message(chat_id=admin_id, from_chat_id=users_id, message_id=message.message_id)
            video_flag = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пересылка без автора называется копирование и это отдельный метод `copy_message`

```
await bot.copy_message(chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id)
```

```
chat_id = 0 # чат куда пересылать
from_chat_id = # чат откуда пересылать
message_id = 0 # айди сообщения
```

можно вот так в хендлере

```
async def handler(message: types.Message)
    await message.copy_to(chat_id)
```

Comment: Всё работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем параметр `disable_notification` в функцию `forward_message` и со значением `True`. Это отключит уведомление получателя о том, что сообщение было переадресовано, и должно имя отправителя не отображаться.

```
await bot.forward_message(chat_id=admin_id, from_chat_id=users_id, message_id=message.message_id, disable_notification=True)
```

Comment: Этот параметр отправляет сообщения без звука. Без уведомлений. К сожалению надпись о том, что сообщение переслали осталось

Comment: брал с документации на английском то, что оно мьютит знаю, но сказано, что при форварде должно и убирать имя отправителя.
эх... хотел как лучше, получилось как всегда=)

Comment: Лучше сказать и ошибиться, чем вообще не сказать. Я перерыл весь интернет, и единственное, что я нашел - https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/issues/136 . Пишут, что добавили это, но в документации ничего не сказано

Comment: ```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.chat.id == support )
async def echo_handler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=client_chat, text=message.text)
```
вот попробуй эту функцию вместо `support ` напиши ид чата куда сбросить . Я это писал для пользователя который передает сообщения из одного чата в другой, но там речь за сообщения а не видео.

Comment: это конечно будет работать, но именно с текстовыми сообщениями. В моем случае надо видео. И именно способом пересылки, ибо так быстрее и нагружает меньше. Видимо такой функции просто нет. Напишу на форум aiogram с просьбой добавить. Думаю такое многим нужно будет.